# Software Installation Icon is invisible after posting but visible while editing

Tags: bug, editing, user-interface

This question is corresponding to the [edit by Eliah Kagan](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/167143/4) to my [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/167143/27559) to

> [Is it possible to have a small indicator showing that updates are available (red for security updates) instead of having the update manager pop up?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/167137/is-it-possible-to-have-a-small-indicator-showing-that-updates-are-available-red)

The issue is while the software centre icon was visible in the edit window, after posting the answer it seems to be gone. This is in edit window:

[image: in edit]

This is after posting:
[image]
How can it be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

I have momentarily fixed the formatting in the post. I will try to see if I can explain what causes the break in the formatting.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, it didn't exist until I added it just now. Can you please check again?

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply, but the issue seems to persist even after your edit.

Comment: I had removed the software installation link (that I had previously added), because it was preventing other text from showing properly. It should be viewable in the editing history.

Comment: @EliahKagan and jrg Should I roll back?